# What does SomeMethod(() => x.Something) mean in C#

Tags: c#, lambda

*(Note the code is an example)*

I have the following syntax:

```
SomeMethod(() => x.Something)
```

What do the first brackets mean in the expression?

I'm also curious how you can get the property name from argument that is being passed in. Is this posssible?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630330/what-does-mean-in-c/630344#630344

Comment: Ok apologies it is a duplicate. I'm curious how it differs from `SomethMethod(x => x.Something)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What do the first brackets mean in the expression?

It's the lambda syntax for a method that takes no parameters. If it took 1 parameter, it'd be:

```
SomeMethod(x => x.Something);
```

If it took n + 1 arguments, then it'd be:

```
SomeMethod((x, y, ...) => x.Something);
```

> I'm also curious how you can get the property name from argument that is being passed in. Is this possible?

If your `SomeMethod` takes an `Expression<Func<T>>`, then yes:

```
void SomeMethod<T>(Expression<Func<T>> e) {
    MemberExpression op = (MemberExpression)e.Body;
    Console.WriteLine(op.Member.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The `()` is an empty argument list. You're defining an anonymous function that takes no arguments and returns `x.Something`.

Edit: It differs from `x => x.Something` in that the latter requires an argument and Something is called on that argument. With the former version `x` has to exist somewhere outside the function and Something is called on that outside `x`. With the latter version there does not have to be an outside x and even if there is, Something is still called on the argument to the function and nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

It's a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).  That is, it's a way to create an anonymous function or delegate.

The general form is:

```
(input parameters) => expression
```

If you have

```
() => expression
```

then you have created a function that takes no arguments, and returns the result of the expression.

C# uses [type inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference) to figure out what the types of the values are, and it captures local variables (like your "x" variable) by means of a [lexical closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)).

Answer (score 2):

I assume x is declared in somewhere inside your method, if yes, you can compare this lambda expression with a delegate that has no paramaters and return the type of x.someproperty

```
delegate{
 return x.someproperty;
}
```

that is the same as:

```
() => x.someproperty
```

Comment: @Dykam, who said it wont? It will. try to compile this example: http://cleigomes.net/powersource/Output.aspx?fl=3w1e3djw.she

Comment: In this example, yes, it does. As i said, the return type will be the type of "x.someProperty"

Answer (score 1):

the () mean that this method doesn't take any parameters. 
for example, if you assign a normal event handler using a lambda expression, it would look like this:

```
someButton.Click += (s, e) => DoSomething();
```

Answer (score 1):

See also the following two blog posts that discuss exactly your second question and provide alternative approaches:

[How to Find Out Variable or Parameter Name in C#?](http://abdullin.com/journal/2008/12/13/how-to-find-out-variable-or-parameter-name-in-c.html)

[How to Get Parameter Name and Argument Value From C# Lambda via IL?](http://abdullin.com/journal/2008/12/19/how-to-get-parameter-name-and-argument-value-from-c-lambda-v.html) (Or "How NOT to Use .NET Linq Expressions in Order to Get Parameter Name and Argument Value From C# Lambda?")

Answer (score 0):

To get the name of the property you need SomeMethod to have an argument of the type of `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<object>>`. You can then go through the expression to determine the property name.