# What does return () mean in C#?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have the following method:

```
protected Func<T> GetMenuItems<T>() where T : IMenuItem, new()
{
    return () => _menuItems.GetMenuItem<T>();
}
```

It's the first time that I ever saw this syntax: `return () => _menuItems.GetMenuItem<T>()` what are these parenthesis for and what do they do?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions

Comment: It's returning a delegate of type `Func<T>`  The body of the delegate being returned is `_menuItems.GetMenuItem<T>();`  The parentheses and the arrow operator are a *lambda expression.*  The empty parentheses indicate that the lambda expression takes no parameters.

Comment: Lambda function. Could also do something like `() => { return _menuItems.GetMenuItem<T>(); }`

Comment: [Explain what's the use of this statement += () => and how it works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52206316/995714), [What does the '=>' syntax in C# mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/290061/995714), [What does SomeMethod(() => x.Something) mean in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1370236/995714)

Comment: Thanks for the comments and answers, I think I need to first learn delegates to understand this.

Answer (score 3):

It returns the whole expression `() => _menuItems.GetMenuItem<T>();` which is a *lambda* notation :

A function taking no parameter `()` (think of `Foo()`), returning the result of `_menuItems.GetMenuItem<T>()`.

It is useful to return this way for instance to do "Lazy execution" : the function GetMenuItem is not yet executed. However the `Func<T>` returned has all the information to execute this inner function.

Comment: Doesn't this capture `_menuItems`? So it may occur, that `_menuItems` (the object it references) lives longer than the object where it is from (if this makes sense)?

Comment: @Fildor you should indeed be careful with this. This will prevent Garbage collector to clean up some resources. But I don't think you will get any trouble about the lifetime of the object in classic cases, apart from retaining resources too long. Maybe I understand it wrong, but that's what the "managed" part of using a managed language permit us to do. I picture you create object "on the heap", and they are cleaned if no more reference to them exist. Have this Func still being referenced, mean the object is still referenced as well.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I was just wondering and thought "this may lead to some interesting debugging sessions". But as you say, it's a feature and you should of course always know what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

It means that returns a function with no parameters "()" which body is

```
{
     return _menuItems.GetMenuItem<T>();
}
```

You can also return functions with parameters in a similar fashion:

```
return (int a) => a++;
```